# Set default node version using nvm

Tags: javascript, node.js, nvm

I am having three versions of my project. And I have three `.nvmrc` files associated with it. In the build server, I use `nvm use` to pick the version that is required for that version. But somehow with the node installed globally, even after nvm use the version is switching back to the globally installed node. Is there some way I can set default version that is currently present in the `nvmrc` file using `nvm` command ?

```
nvm use
// may be something like this. Not sure if the below one exists
nvm use default
```

Can someone assist here?

Comment: try `nvm alias default node_version` for example `nvm alias default v20.3.0`

Comment: Depending on your console of choice, you can also [automatically read the .nvmrc file](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#deeper-shell-integration) and switch to that version, each time you change your project directory.